# How to get the text within a span in a tooltip via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, tooltip, tooltipster

I am trying to get the text within a span to be the 'content' of a tooltip using the [Tooltipster jQuery plugin](http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster).

A description of the available parameters for the 'content' option can be seen here:

http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/#options

**JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.tooltip').tooltipster({
content: $(this).parent().text() // trying to get the span text here
});
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<p>Here is some text, and here is <span class="tooltip" data-rlink="<a href=&quot;http://www.google.com&quot;>a link</a>">SOME MORE</span> text.</p>
<p>And the content should be <span class="tooltip">UNIQUE</span> to the instance.</p>
```

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/y9uGh/1/

**Solution**

Based on the answer below, this was the implementation I went with.  The snippet below shows integration of the js solution with the plugins parameters:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.tooltip').tooltipster({
functionBefore: function(origin, continueTooltip){
origin.tooltipster('update', $(origin).text());
continueTooltip();
},
animation: 'grow',
arrow: false,
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: if you found the answer useful, would you mind marking it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
        functionBefore: function(origin, continueTooltip){
            origin.tooltipster('update', $(origin).text());
            continueTooltip();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/X88u3/)

Comment: This solution adds the text within the `<p>` tags to the tooltip.  I am trying to add the text within the `<span>` tags to the tooltip.

Comment: @user1063287 you mean for the second tooltip, you want to display `UNIQUE`? like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/X88u3/2/

Comment: For any instance where there is a span which has an associated tooltip, the text within the `<span>` tags should be what is displayed in the tooltip.  So in the example above, the first tooltip should be `SOME MORE` and the second tooltip should be `UNIQUE`.