# Any extra steps required to ensure jQuery functionality on dynamic content fetched by getJSON?

Tags: php, jquery, getjson

I have just learnt how to use jQuery's `getJSON` method with a PHP file making queries on a MySQL database then running the results through PHP's `json_encode`.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".click_me").click(function(){
$.getJSON("http://path/to/file.php",function(results){  
$("#container").html(results[0].key-name);
});
});
});
</script>
```

The functionality is working except that the returned data (html) has classes wrapped around some content which should be triggering jQuery actions on hover and click etc.

None of this functionality is working though and I am wondering if there is some sort of 'reinitialisation' that needs to take place on the content as it is 'dynamically' generated by the `getJSON` method?

Comment: What do your event listeners look like that are listening on clicks and hover?

Comment: The exact code can be seen in the original post here under the bold heading `Solution`:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179242/how-to-get-the-text-within-a-span-in-a-tooltip-via-jquery

Comment: I see no `$(selector).on('click', function() {});` so how are you actually trying to trigger events on click/hover?

Comment: The code linked to above shows an implementation of the `Tooltipster` jQuery plugin which doesn't require click actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handlers that you have attached to the page at load were attached only to those elements that were present during the call. So you need to either
1. Attach them again by calling teh functions
2. Use `$.on`

1. Suppose you added the handler `$(".someClass").click(dosomething)`. You can call this line again and the handler will be reattached to the class. Do this after ajax call.
2. You can use `$(".someClass").on("click",dosomething)` to add the event handler. Just check the format of on. I am not entirely sure of the syntax

Edit: In response to comment

```
function initTooltipster(){ //Move it to  a seperate function we can call
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
        functionBefore: function(origin, continueTooltip){
            origin.tooltipster('update', $(origin).text());
            continueTooltip();
        }
    });

}
$(document).ready(initTooltipster);

 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".click_me").click(function () {
         $.getJSON("http://path/to/file.php", function (results) {
             $("#container").html(results[0].key - name);
             initTooltipster();//Init it here again
             //OR just call tooltipster inside the context of container                                    $('#container .tooltip').tooltipster({
        functionBefore: function(origin, continueTooltip){
            origin.tooltipster('update', $(origin).text());
            continueTooltip();
        }
    });


         });
     });
 });
```

Comment: The exact code (that shows the jQuery that is not working) can be seen in the original post here under the bold heading `Solution`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179242/how-to-get-the-text-within-a-span-in-a-tooltip-via-jquery  As there is no `click`, how would I apply it in this scenario?

Comment: How would I apply the `.on` method in this scenario I mean.

Comment: The most elegant way to do it was to create the function at the top and then call it after the dynamic content had been added with `initTooltipster()` as you demonstrated.